# str_replace with multiple arguments

Tags: regex, string, r, pcre

`enter code here`i got a problem with extracting string. I want to extract Streetnames out of the streetnames+housenumbers. Problem is some streetnames contain numbers. Can I combine more than one pattern to extract strings?

```
w<-c("STREET TEST 55A","Q 7 NR 50","STREET TEST TEST 55-56")
place<-c("B" "A" "C")

    w<-str_replace(w,perl("^(\\b[0-9]+.*\\b) | \\b([A-Z] ?[0-9] ?N?R?)([0-9]*)\\b"),"\\1")
```

I want a vector

```
w<-c("STREET TEST","Q 7","STREET TEST TEST)
```

I also have a vector place. And the case `Q 7 NR 50` only occurs in place `A` but not in place `B/C`
Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect your actual problem may be unsolvable in general, at least unless your data is restricted to a small geographical area with regular street naming and house numbering conventions. You _might_ get away with assuming that street names don't _usually_ contain numbers, and adding specific rules for the few exceptions you encounter. Even then, if your data is global, you may need to deal with the extra issue that, in different parts of the world, the convention may be to write the street name either before, after, or possibly between the house numbers. Also, houses might have names.

Answer (score 1):

I am making an assumption that if the last word contains only digits then you need the second last word as well to make the housename. If this assumption is valid, the following code works

```
w<-c("STREET TEST 55A","Q 7 NR 50","STREET TEST TEST 55-56")
library(stringr)
housename <- ifelse(nchar(gsub("[[:digit:]]","",word(w,-1)))==0
,paste(word(w,-2),word(w,-1),sep=" ")
,word(w,-1))
streetname <- str_replace_all(w,housename,"")
```

> housename
>   [1] "55A"   "NR 50" "55-56"
>   streetname
>   [1] "STREET TEST "      "Q 7 "              "STREET TEST TEST "